# Is it correct to use 'you'?

Tags: grammaticality

Can we use the subject 'you' for emphasis in the imperative?

> 1. Don't you learn the lessons by heart!
> 2. Don't you forget it!

Comment: no, but I can't say why. You may see "don't you forget it" used but it is casual language.

Comment: I think these looks odd, but I see no reason why they couldn't be used. (Perhaps in the right context.) If it's okay to say *Don't you do that!* then I think these examples are similarly okay. It's simply that they're not normally heard.

Comment: A quick Ngram Viewer check indicates that the popularity of the construction **Don't you** has grown steadily over the past 200 years.

Answer (score 2):

For me, (western United States native speaker) I get the sense that the added 'you' lends some playfulness to the meaning, especially when paired with 'go' which is a common case. For example "Don't make me look bad." is a fairly harsh thing to say, but "Don't you go making me look bad." is playful. It also has a sort of innocent 1930-1950's ring to it. It's possible that it sounds somewhat condescending as if speaking to child, and that's why it can be playful. I can picture my grandma saying "Zeal, you eat your peas."

You might also come across a stressed *you* inserted into the statement to contrast with what someone else has done. For example, "I have a hard time remembering appointments, so don't *you* forget."